# Typescript: method to check if value is: null, undefined, '', [], or {}

Tags: typescript

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKhFgCgAIWglApgFwK4CcB21ntY6ASwDNoA3AQwBt8iBnaC6AIkQFsAHZAT2fOoA00RAHMAXNEyoqVIakwATRMUKZECoQHJNQgNoBdIQG8AvkIAMUWMCiIAHhwD26ZNADGjzHVeE6AOWkqAHl0AFVFZVV1EIBRTh5oAF5oAApKGkQJCkxuAEoJdNpfSUDoAB9oeSUVNQVy6G16g3rTevMkgD5oIysiUjTqWkThkplyisKCYeSqyNrx-gykkcayicGpkfNc7t7oaHQUDGxcfABuXpNeklSeDkRHUknl5M0pNgAjRHRNaAAyP70PwUPwDDK5HY9GD7A5HLA4PCIC7Qq7Qm4pO4PJ4bF4NRwfABWiDcyE0kL2fVSAEF0OgKNwAHS%20Gl07hg-AQ3bQmGwtDwyYMqiITAiZAAC2gAB5kuZkTyTMIqHQCFCeftDnzsEFCcTkAyANaIbh0dmIXKC4WiiXTaDtAGLfAMjxeU4k5y47VEklymGo-Z%203nHaDEajK5EmZFQKOQZ3eHCIbxxLjcJLdCNQEgpaAAQl8ARkIXC1SiCli8TZyATyCTPB2uVVMOo32QGKrNcZFFyUFRUFjrkr3j8jmr5dTRgoElOiHTkEzObzgULERq0XQ7dbg%20H7brDf2TZcG%20QQ5HyYZne7QA)

I want set the return type of this method to check if the value is: null, undefined, '', [], or {}.

```
/**
 * Return true if value is a "empty" val, eg: null, undefined, '', [], {}, 0
 */
export const isNullOrUndefinedOrEmpty = (value: any): value is null | undefined | '' | [] | {} | 0 => {
  if (value === null || value === undefined || value === '' || value === 0) {
    return true;
  }
  if (typeof value === 'number' && isNaN(value)) {
    return true;
  }
  if (typeof value === 'object') {
    if (Array.isArray(value)) {
      return value.length <= 0;
    } else {
      return Object.keys(value).length === 0 && value.constructor === Object;
    }
  }
  return false;
};
```

Usage

```
const testEmpty = {};
if( !isNullOrUndefinedOrEmpty(testEmpty) ){
    alert(testEmpty.a)
}

const testNotEmpty = {a: true};
if( !isNullOrUndefinedOrEmpty(testNotEmpty) ){
    alert(testNotEmpty.a)
}
```

But, ts raise this error on both example?

> Property 'a' does not exist on type 'never'.

Comment: `typeof value === 'object'` does not check if object has 0 keys (that is `{}`).
Use `Object(o).keys.length === 0` when o is non empty object

Comment: Interestingly, the compilation error disappears in the second example with `testNotEmpty` when the negation (`!`) is removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type `{}` in TypeScript does not mean "empty object", it means "any value besides `null` or `undefined`".

The library type-fest provides an EmptyObject type:

```
declare const emptyObjectSymbol: unique symbol;
type EmptyObject = {[emptyObjectSymbol]?: never};
```

source: https://github.com/sindresorhus/type-fest/blob/main/source/empty-object.d.ts

Comment: Alternatively `Record<never, never>`

Comment: Quote from the documentation on EmptyObject: "
Unfortunately, `Record<string, never>`, `Record<keyof any, never>` and `Record<never, never>` do not work. See {@link https://github.com/sindresorhus/type-fest/issues/395 #395}."